# RAILS: Internet Explorer 8 not rendering actions, download popup instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller and all of the actions are not render by IE8, in Firefox and Chromer works ok. The problem is only with this controller, i have another that work ok.

The code is:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
 auto_complete_for :customers, :name

 def search
   unless params[:q].nil?
    @customers = Customer.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?',
        "%#{params[:q]}%"])
   end

   respond_to do |format|
     format.xml { render :xml => @customers}
     format.json { render :json => @customers}
   end

end

def index  
  @customers = Customer.find_index
end

def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
end
```

For example the index action is not getting render and instead IE8 display a download dialog, but if i edit the index action like this:

```
def index
  @customers = Customer.find_index // a find all but ordered.
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Any ideas what is happening?

**UPDATE**:
For all of you interested, the problem was the templates files names.
All the files with a name like "invoice.erb" was sent back to the browser as content "text/erb" while the files like "customers.html.erb" was sent back as "text/html". 
Once i renamed all the file to "html.erb" everything works ok

Comment: Just curious, why would you be hitting this endpoint in a browser? An endpoint that only returns xml and json is usually called by AJAX. If you're just trying to test them out to make sure they work, well, you should be writing tests for that.

Comment: @Samo: are you talking about the search method? If it so, im using it only for ajax method and some testing via browser as you said.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry I misunderstood, you're saying that none of the actions are rendering correctly in IE8 unless you explicitly render html. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

ie8 doesn't know what to do with xml or json but does know what to do with html.  If you really want the browser to display the xml you could add `:content_type => 'text/plain'` to the block so it knows how to respond to it.

Comment: Do you meant that is the search method  the cause of the problem, even if im not calling it from ie8?

Comment: if you want the search method to render in a browser you need to either give it a content type that the browser will know what to do with OR give it a html block so it can render something.  IE is popping the save dialog because it doesn't know what to do with application/xml